# JS filter textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope this isn't a daft question. I expected google to be promising but I failed today.

I have a textbox `<input type="text" id="input1" />` that I only want to accept the input `/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/`. I want to bind something to the keydown event and ignore invalid keys but charCode isn't robust enough. Is there a good jQuery plugin that does this?

The affect I want to achieve is for some one to type 'hello world! 12.345' and want all characters to be ignored except '12.34' and the textbox to read '12.34'. Hope this is clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. Cache the last valid input on `keydown` event
2. Rollback to last valid input on `keyup` event if invalid input detected

Thus:

```
var cache = {};
$(function() {
    $("input[regex]").bind("keydown", function() {
        var regex = new RegExp($(this).attr("regex"));
        if (regex.test($(this).val())) {
            cache[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
        }
    });
    $("input[regex]").bind("keyup", function() {
        var regex = new RegExp($(this).attr("regex"));
        if (!regex.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).val(cache[$(this).attr("id")]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a plugin to do this; you could easily attach an event and write a simple callback to do it yourself like so:

```
$('#input1').keyup(function()
{
    // If this.value hits a match with your regex, replace the current 
    // value with a sanitized value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#input1').change(function(){
    if($(this).data('prevText') == undefined){
          $(this).data('prevText', ''); 
    }
    if(!isNaN($(this).val())){
        $(this).val($(this).data('prevText'))
    } 
    else {
        //now do your regex to check the number settings
        $(this).data('prevText', $(this).val()); 
    }

})
```

the `isNAN` function checks to make sure the value is a number

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input1').bind('keyup', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(!val)
        return;
    var match = val.match(/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/);
    if(!match)
        return;
    //replace the value of the box, or do whatever you want to do with it
    $(this).val(match[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Keyfilter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-keyfilter/)

Usage:

```
$('#ggg').keyfilter(/[\dA-F]/);
```

It also supports some pre-made filters that you can assign as a css class.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input1').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val().match(/\d+([.]\d{1,2})?/);
    val = val == null || val.length == 0 ? "" : val[0];
    $(this).val(val);
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It looks like you you typed in something that doesn't match the regex it will empty the input.

Comment: the man said "ignore invalid keys".. so if you type in anything invalid... the input's value does not change

Comment: Yes but [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/haochi/uhJ3c/) isn't doing what you think it does.

Comment: Didn't quite understood what you were pointing out, but thx, it seems that i have forgotten an "[0]" which would've put the first matched element ( instead of an array of matches) as the input's val. now it (http://jsfiddle.net/uhJ3c/1/) works.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). You can define your own checking methods [like this here](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js).